# What is the best way to exploit multicores when making multithread games?

Tags: multithreading

Many people suggest to write a program, and then start optimizing it. But I think that when it's coming to multithreading with multicore, a little think ahead is required.
I've read about using threads, and experienced it myself during some courses at the university (still a student).

The big question is simple, but a bit abstract:

> What thread related steps in game design do I need to take, **before** implementation?

Now trying to be more *specific*. Let's say, as an example, that I'm making a small board game  (like Monopoly) that I want to be multithreaded.
My goal Is that this multithreaded game will exploit the best of the multicore system, lets say 4-6 cores (like in i7 processors).

My answer to this question at the moment is, one thread for each of these four basic components:

- GUI
- User Input / Output
- AI (computer rival)
- Other game related calculations (like shortest path from A to B, or level up status change)

I'm not an expert (yet!), and I'm sure there are better answers out there.
Any suggestion, answer, different approach will be helpful.

**Some thoughts:**
Maybe splitting the main database is a good way.. (or total disaster.. )

Comment: @TrevorPowell Well, I didn't see it when I asked.. But my questions is not an exact duplicate of it.

Answer (score 5):

It's usually not a great idea to try and have different subsystems on different threads, because safe communication between them is often too expensive. I wouldn't want to have to use a mutex every time I recorded a mouse movement, for example. And putting AI in a separate thread creates a game design problem in real-time games; does this risk making the AI more responsive or more powerful on more powerful computers? One exception is for audio and specifically the primary buffer handling - it's common to have that in another thread because it's important that audio is being handled in a timely manner and avoids dropouts; but luckily this is usually done for you by most audio libraries.

Generally the best approach is to implement the game as a series of tasks which the different threads can execute in parallel. This scales well to as many threads as you have. You would still usually have the input-update-render loop, but the update section (and the data-processing part of the rendering) can often be split into many distinct tasks that operate on discrete pieces of data.

The most important game design concern when using such an approach is to think about how things can be updated in isolation - you can't have one of object A's update tasks altering object B or even trying to query the present state of object B, as object B may be getting altered in a different thread at the same time. So you could:

- Ensure items that depend on each other are always processed by the same thread, perhaps by packing them into the same task;
- Keep 2 copies of each object's state so that you can always safely read from the old one while amending the new one;
- Send a copy of object B to object A's update task (which is basically an ad-hoc version of the previous approach);
- Make changes via some sort of transaction and apply them via optimistic locking, repeating if it fails (which again basically copies the object and uses versioning and locking to see whether it's safe to write back into the original).

These are all pretty tricky to get right, which is why you need to think ahead as you said.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about game engine design not game design.. but getting to the topic.

Multithreading makes sense when you have logical tasks which can be divided into parts (or one logical task dividable into sub-tasks).

Normally in single threaded game you would:

1. check user input

   - Normally os makes this "multithreded" for you as in typical situation you are just notified about clicks, touches and key presses (on mobile), and\or you polls input state like mouse position and key press state - but I don't think it is worth to put input check code into separate thread, because if your os is sending you input events, then it already is on separate thread and you just adds additional layer of complexity. Again, if you poll for input device state every frame, then your code afterwards probably depends heavily on that state, so even if you put polling in separate thread, your main thread would have to wait for the results.
2. compute ai actions and "other game related calculations" as you named it.

   - Here you can experiment with multithreading. Think about producers and consumers pattern. For example once in a while you have a queue of units from which your code could grab objects and initiate a "computePathCommand" for each object in different thread.
3. render game and ui

   - This should be tested but I don't think you will gain much if anything by pushing triangles to OpenGL or DirectX from separate threads simultaneously.  From http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_and_multithreading: "..it doesn't improve performance. GL function calls go to the driver and the driver collects the function calls into command lists, which finally get sent to the GPU. Usually there is just 1 GPU so there is no performance increase."

So to sum it up. Multithreading make sense mostly in the "calculations" part, think about dividable tasks in your game, prepare those tasks, create threads which will work on those tasks*, wait for threads to finish, render/draw the results, repeat :).

- Aditional tip - creating more threads than cpu cores, will not bring you performance increase.

Comment: `Aditional tip - creating more threads than cpu cores, will not bring you performance increase.` That's not necessarily true. Having critical threads block on IO can be a big problem.

Comment: Having more threads *busy* than cpu cores will not bring performance. In fact, it can (and will) hurt performance.

Comment: And that's what I have written, or..?

Answer (score 2):

One thing I haven't seen in any answers yet is a split-and-join tactic. This works particularly well when there are numerous cores available (like the PS3's SPUs), or where excessive IO blocking would cause the CPU to be underutilized.

If you have a lot of work that can be calculated independently, you can spawn several threads (or a thread pool) to do the work, give each thread some work, then wait for them all to finish (join) and then move on. This has the advantage of being a fairly localized design change (most of the other things talked about so far have very far-reaching design considerations). However, it can be difficult to find a situation where something like this would actually work and pay off.

Comment: That is pretty much the task-based approach that I was referring to, but perhaps I didn't make it clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

What you have isn't a bad way to start, but I'd make the UI thread the main game thread as well.  Work out a strong messaging system with commands and command queues for the different threads to communicate so that you minimize the number of synchronization points.

Other places that could be threaded depending on your implementation:

- Sound
- Physics/Animation
- Resource Loading
- Networking

Basically think of different subsystems and think, "Would it be bad if this system was one to two frames out of sync with this other system."  If it isn't then they could be off-loaded.

And for some of the answers above, Multi-threaded rendering doesn't mean rendering from multiple threads usually, but rather moving the rendering from the main game thread so that you are not locking the FPS of the renderer to the FPS of other parts of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

Here's my input:

Maybe monopoly isn't the best example for intensive needs for computation, but i get your point.
Also, it's a good idea to plan the architecture as thoroughly as possible, and sooner, rather than later!

I'd say that the best use for multicores should be paralelization of AI calculations, as they are the most resource-hungry aspects i can think of, other than graphics (except if you somehow decide to have an extremely detailed 3d monopoly board).
But from here, any solution is deeply linked to the game you're coding.

What do you mean by "splitting the main database"?

Comment: It was just a thought.. When you have a main source from which all threads read, it can make multithreading useless.. Something like splitting the data to more used, and less used.. I didn't give it much thought...

Comment: hum, that may depend on the ammount of data you're handling (AI calcs can generate a lot of data) - but for storing a board, pieces and things like that, it's probably not worth it.

Answer (score -2):

I invoke the Wisdom of the Ancients:

### Yoda says

> Bad premature optimisation is. Exceptions this does not have.

### Brian Kernighan says

> Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.

Threading is optimisation. It's *very clever* optimisation.

Do it only once it becomes necessary or you will wind up writing, debugging and pondering all things inconsequential. Certainly don't *start* with it!

Comment: Mysterious are the ways of the force...

Comment: "Yes, a Jedi's strength flows from the Force. But beware of the dark side."

Comment: In general, I agree with what you're saying regarding optimisation, but I think this situation is different. For example, if your entity update requires access to the world in order to iterate over other entities, then your ability to spread that across multiple threads is already severely limited.

Comment: The true master knows that exceptions this does have.  Don't forget that what Knuth actually said was: "97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.  Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.  A good programmer will not be lulled into complacency by such reasoning; he will be wise to look carefully at the critical code; but only after that code has been identified".  I see this misquoted (or partially quoted) as reasoning against any kind of optimization so often, and it's borderline annoying...

Comment: I don't really agree with the message in this answer. Threading issues are best considered before the interactions of large systems are implemented. At the same time, they are very pivotal points of design in the system and are huge points of optimization. A good high-level design will include consideration of multithreaded implementation. Premature optimization can certainly be a bad thing, but when designing large systems and their interactions, multithreading considerations are not necessarily "premature." After all, we're talking about some of the *biggest* decisions that will be involved.

Comment: I'm deliberately annoying. I thought any discussion I could cause would be necessary and constructive. I expected a better discussion, though. Gentlemen and gentlewomen, please *cite your sources*! I cite heavy history. I cite the heaps of videogame vapourware that died of featuritis before birth. I cite those miserable hundreds of uncompleted hobbyist game development projects. I see no mythical 3 percent, only death caused by the other 97.

Comment: stephelton is definitely correct here.  If you don't design around multithreading considerations, if you try to retro-fit it after the fact, you WILL create a mess.  Multithreading simply cannot be considered an optimization - premature or otherwise - these days.  It's an up-front design decision.

Comment: My source is Knuth's original paper that is so often misquoted (or partially quoted) - "structured programming with goto statements" - PDF copy available here: http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~mak/CS185C/KnuthStructuredProgrammingGoTo.pdf  pop down to page 8, things begin happening in the second paragraph of the second column.

Comment: @Anko: It seems like you have never worked on a high-performance game engine before. Do you think having 4 cores inside a PC and not using them makes sense?

Comment: @Dudeson You're right, but if your game doesn't end up needing that highly concurrent engine, you'll have wasted dev time. Programmer time is more expensive than machine time. Of course, as with everything, experts can divine future needs and take design shortcuts, but *they* don't need advice. However, for OP's "small board game", having "read about using threads", if introducing unnecessary complexity is like shooting yourself in the foot, then *starting a board game design with concurrency considerations* is like shooting yourself in the foot *with a cruise missile*.

Comment: @Anko: "shooting yourself in the foot with a cruise missile" LOL! You are right. But keep in mind, Keeper's board game was just an example (a not so good one for this problem). He was asking about multithreading in games in general.